# Prevent < > ^ chars leaking out of variable

Tags: shell-script, nemo, zenity

I think my script halts because the text it's about to display contains "commands"

A code that displays the first 20 lines of a subtitles file:

```
junknownsub=$(head -20 "$f")
zenity --question  --text="$jsubtitle\n\nIs this English?\n\n$junknownsub"  --width=200 --height=200
```

this is the text:

```
0
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:18,338
<b><font color="#909090">^.^.^.^.movie .^.^.^.^</font></b>
<b><font color="#804040">®</font></b> <b><font color=#ff0000> </font></b> <b><font color="#804040">®</font></b>
```

This causes linux to popup this question: [image: popup]

I suspect it's the < >^ chars that's messing things up, because all "normal" text works without any issues..

Anyway to work around this?

a previous suggestion I got was:
`printf -v junknownsub '%q' $(head -n20 "$f")`
but that only froze nemo

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/606680

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some dialogs displayed by [GNOME Zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/index.html.en_GB) support the [pango markup language](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/pango-markup-language.html) and, by default, interpret it in the dialog text. `zenity` is parsing the text in your sample as invalid pango markup. It is not a shell issue.

To prevent this you can:

- Use the `--no-markup` option. As a downside, the markup will be shown literally, including the `\n` sequences you are using to format the dialog text.
- Pre-process your subtitle text to remove the markup.